# Declaring a template that resolves to another template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm working with heavily templated code, where I've got a lot of "helpers" implementing somewhat common base functionality that's missing in the STL. For example:

```cpp
// is_instance_v determines whether the type argument passed is an instance of the given template
// e.g. is_instance_v<std::vector<int>, std::vector> is true
template<typename, template<typename...> typename>
constexpr bool is_instance_v = false;
template<typename... Ts, template<typename...> typename U>
constexpr bool is_instance_v<U<Ts...>, U> = true;
```

This is a pretty useful little template. But now I've got other templates where I want to use this in a more generic way. I'd like if I could use `is_instance_v` as a template argument to something while only *partially* specifying type arguments. That way I can pass it to a template which takes a template parameter, and let it fill in the rest. Essentially, I want a template that turns into a template, like so:

```cpp
// not working code - just the kind of thing I'm envisioning
template<template<typename> typename Template>
template<typename T>
using instance_comparator_t = is_instance_v<T, Template>;

// instance_comparator_t<std::vector> can now be passed to another template that expects a template<typename> arg
```

The above example however doesn't work. This is because, as I understand it, `using` declarations are for *types*, and this is a template.

Possible valid solutions I've thought of:

- Manually specifying each case as a separate `constexpr bool`, i.e. `is_instance_of_vector<T>`

  - This works, but it just moves the problem out another layer of abstraction without really solving it.
- A templated `constexpr` function

  - I *think* this works, but then the template has to call it.
  - Any template I write that could take a constexpr function is now incompatible with all the STL templates, when they otherwise don't have to be.

Is there a better way? I'm open to solutions for any version of C++, including upcoming ones.

Comment: It is precisely to permit such usage that STL defines e.g. `std::is_same` with `value` member, and separately `std::is_same_v` as a shorthand for `is_same::value`. This way `std::is_same` could be passed somewhere as a template template parameter. You could do the same with `is_instance` and `is_instance_v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap `is_instance_v` in a class template like as shown below:

```
template<typename, template<typename> typename Template> struct Test
{
   template<typename, template<typename...> typename>
   static constexpr bool is_instance_v = false;
   template<typename... Ts, template<typename...> typename U>
   static constexpr bool is_instance_v<U<Ts...>, U> = true;

};

template<typename T, template<typename> typename Template>
using instance_comparator_t = Test<T, Template>;

template<typename T, template<typename> typename Template>
constexpr bool instance_comparator_v = instance_comparator_t<T, Template>::is_instance_v;
```

Comment: A slightly modified version of this did the trick!

Comment: (Sorry for double-posting)
The solution was to essentially take the `Test` struct you outlined here, but omit the first `typename` argument. Then you can produce a template containing a `::value` which is itself a template, that some other template can pass arguments to for results. A bit awkward, but STL compatible. Just don't forget it's a rare case where you actually need a `template` keyword (e.g. `Test<T>::template value<U>`)